# Split char after finding dot in c++

Tags: c++, char

I am working with `char` in C++. I have already properly set the `char[]` that I am looking for but it contains information that I do not need. `ObjectName`  is composed by name and a property. The structure is "name.property" and I would like to get only the property part (`string` after the dot).

```
if (strcmp(objectName, "") != 0) {
        char fullName[32];
        char *mqttAddress;
        sprintf(fullName, "test/%s", objectName);
        mqttAddress = strtok(fullName, ".");

        sprintf(payload, "%s, %.5f,%.5f", mqttAddress, x, y);
        mqttPublishMessage(payload, mqttAddress );

    }
```

How could I divide the `string` after the dot and storing the value in `mqttAddress` or any other variable? And example would be:

```
objectName = "name.property"
```

The expected result would be `property`

I have tried using:

```
            mqttAddress = strtok(fullName, ".");
```

but the result is `name`

Another approach would be to get the string after the `position` 8 of `fullName` or maybe by using something like `strtok` after finding `test.`

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Doesn't it work as you expect? How doesn't it work as you expect?

Comment: I have edited the question. I forgot to mention something. My fault

Comment: You might want to read [a `strtok` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)? I would rather suggest the [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) instead (together with some basic arithmetic)

Comment: I just want to find the second part of the array. Is it possible? In the documentation I find always a while which returns all the ocurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::string_view`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  std::string_view const s = "name.property";
  auto pos = s.find('.');
  assert(pos != std::string_view::npos); // Do your error checking.
  ++pos;
  auto const property = s.substr(pos);
  std::cout << property;
}
```

If you just want to use the C library:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  char const * const str = "name.property";
  char const * property = std::strchr(str, '.');
  assert(property); // Error handling
  ++property;
  std::puts(property);
}
```

Comment: I need to use char due to a library

Comment: @Mario what is stopping you from assigning `std::string_view s = char_array;`?

Comment: I mean that the end result must be stored in a char. As I said I m crazy new in C++. Can I do it?

Comment: @Mario of course! `const char* res = property.data();`

Comment: Is it possible to work with char? I m trying to keep it as simple as possible. No extra libraries. Just to know if i could do it with char, even knowing that there are other odds

Comment: I have upload the end of the question. Maybe it is easier in this way.

Comment: This totally works. Thanks for your help. I have marked your answer as correct cause it actually answer my original question. But one thing else, is it possible to remove also the "." from the result? So it does not return ".property"

Comment: This answer does remove the dot.

Comment: And you are completely right again. Thanks buddy. Works like charm (I just forgot to add ++)